# AWS DMS task fails

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, data-migration, aws-dms

Having some problems using DMS - misconfigure the task selection rule (i guess)

testing it between 2 small rds postgres instances
created source and target endpoints
created a replication instances
( tested connections successfuly  )

```
The task i run keeps failing : 
" Last Error No tables were found at task initialization. 
Either the selected table(s) or schemas(s) no longer exist or no match was found for the table selection pattern(s)."
```

Schemas :
pg_catalog,information_schema,public

I only want to replicate a single DB called test_db

What should i use in the selection rule ?

[image]

Comment: hey..anyone knows ?

Comment: Does your DB have more than one schema ?

Comment: Im not very familiar with databases,but i checked ( also in the question body ) and there are 3 schemas ( pg_catalog,information_schema,public )

Comment: Does the above settings give you any errors in cloud watch? is it worth splitting it into 3 task?

Comment: Hey manged to make it work,but faced another problem..getting error when replicating the data.ERROR: null value in column "name" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint; Error while executing the query but i used INSERT INTO users VALUES(12,'twelve');

Comment: Are you truncating or dropping the tables?

Comment: no,chose only to replicate changes and to not drop tables,created a new question if you can check please - thanks !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69175814/aws-dms-fails-to-replicate-data

Comment: me too facing same issues.

Comment: @EyalSolomon How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, my user didn't have the proper permissions/roles in my source MongoDB. My user couldn't access the schema, nor could it read from the tables, thus the error. If anyone sees this error, I suggest creating a user (or granting your user) with super permissions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Spot on.. This is usually an error when the user does not have proper permission. This error is because your task, thus the user you are using on the dms task to read the source is not able to find these tables. Also check out the answer above with the kind of selection rule you can use. It would be interesting to check detailed debug logs wherein you can get the exact step where your task is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass testDB as the schema.

"rules": [{
"rule-type": "selection",
"rule-id": "1",
"rule-name": "1",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "test_db",
"table-name": "%"
},
"rule-action": "include"
}]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have this error after I set up `Selection rules` on my migration tasks.

My source and target endpoints test the connection successfully.
and I m pretty sure my source database `schema` and `tables` name are correct on my `Selection rules`.

Even I click `Action` and then `modify` the Selection rules again, it still showing this error.

However, I fix it by clicking `Action` and choosing `Restart/Reusme`, then it works... and migrates the data successfully.