# AWS DMS fails to replicate data

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, data-migration, aws-dms

**Problem im facing** - only some columns gets detected

Created a source and target endpoints and a replication instance ( connection tested for both )

Want to copy a table called users that look like this :

[image]

Mapping rules :

[image]

I insert data on source DB

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES(13,'test');
```

But on target DB i get a weird error on awsdms_apply_exception table

```
ERROR - RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 23502 NativeError: 1 Message: ERROR: null value in column "name" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint;
Error while executing the query
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like DMS is ignoring the "name" column. Please make sure that the id is the primary key on the source database.

Comment: you got it ! checked and it wasn't , then created the text with id as a primary key and now it work thanks !

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

As @NItin Vaja said

Problem was table column 'id' wasn't primary key.

Recreated the table with 'id' as a primary key and the
n migration worked !